# TFS 2015 test case Web UI does not display data in columns

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-2015, mtm

I have a few users who are not able to see the Details of test cases.

They can see the test plans. The test plan is Active.

They do not have permission to create test cases but they should be able to see them and run them. Some of the test cases in the test plan have a state of Ready. Some have a state of design.

The users have access to see and run tests but their display looks like this:
[image]

If they try to run the test case they get the message "You cannot run the selected tests. The test case no longer exists. " which is clearly wrong because I and other users can see the test.

The users in question have visibility to the area and iterations.

I'm stumped and I'm sure it's something simple. Why is all of the column data blank?

Answer (score 2):

This can be an issue with area-path permissions. Even though I see that you have mentioned "The users in question have visibility to the area and iterations", I'd like you to try this simple task:

Ask the user who is not able to see the tests in Test hub to head over to the Work hub and write a simple work item query to see if she can access those test case work items in Work hub. You can find out the test case work item IDs from someone who is able to see the test case work items in this test plan. Or you can write a generic query for all test case work items and see of the test case work items that have gone missing in Test hub are showing up in Work hub.

If you are not able to access the test case work items in Work hub, then its an area path permissions issue. If not, I'll be glad to ask someone on my team to look into this. Please reach out to us at devops_tools@microsoft.com

Thanks,
Manoj

Comment: this was actually helpful. By running a query for test cases by Work Item ID in the project in question and NOT seeing any results I realized the test cases were being pulled from a different project.

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed a problem with the areas. But not in the project in question.

The test cases in question pulled in from a **different** project. Everything looked normal if you opened the test case. No errors about invalid area paths. And all the permissions on the project looks ok. The user had all appropriate permissions. If just wasn't until I added up all the pieces I saw the disconnect.,